# What is on my heap? C linux

Tags: c, linux, heap-memory

So I called malloc(1024) today to just play around with the heap. I for the most part understand the structure of the heap, so when I printed out what was in memory, I wasn't surprised to see "00000000 00000409 00000000 00000000 ...."

however 1032 bytes later, I expected to find the top chunk of the heap. Instead I found another chunk as if another call of malloc(1024) had happened after my initial one.

In this chunk is the following:

```
00000000 00000409 30387830 65336234
30203a30 30303030 20303030 30303030
30303030 30303020 30303030 30302030
34303030 33203930 33303330 20303330
30333033 30333032 33343320 33303330
33332030 39333032 000a3233 00000000
```

which translates to:

```
08x0e3b40 :00000 00000000000000 000000 040003 903030 03003030302343 303033#09302 
23
```

Does anyone know why this exists? I am sure I am only calling malloc once. And it always seems to be there no matter what size I malloc.

Comment: Because there are other things going on on your machine? Also what did you expect to be there? (e.g.: What is *"the top chunk of the heap"*?)

Comment: You didn't by any chance call print with a string containing a bunch of zeros?  ASCII 30303030?

Comment: The amount of the move in the `brk`(change in the data segment size) depends on the allocator. It might move it more than what you actually requested in your `malloc` call. So, your data is not necessarily on the top of the heap.

Comment: Do several runs of your program, with other programs running between, or a reboot in between, show the same results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc` reservers a particular amount of memory on the heap and gives back a pointer to this memory block (or `NULL`, if it was not able to allocate the desired memory block). Note, however, that `malloc` will not initialise the memory block in any way. It will not fill it with `0` or any other value; it will simply keep it's content as is.

So the question is actually "what is the initial content of the heap when a program starts?". And the answer is: it depends on the operating system, which portion of memory it assigns to a program when executed, and the content of this memory block is very likely to be just "something undefined", not even random. This can be some recurring patterns of values, it can be zeros, it can be everything.

When you look into different portions of a program's heap, you will probably see this "something undefined" content, regardless of whether you have used `malloc` before or not. You may see recurring patterns as in your case. Note, however, that "looking into" portions of the heap that have not been allocated before is actually undefined behaviour.